# Setting up subdomain on one .com to point to the subdomain on another .com shows cPanel welcome

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, configuration

I have 2 domains on 2 different servers, using two different sets of nameservers. In the DNS settings for the first TLD, lets say foo.com, I have the @ pointing to server1 which is running a specialty site hosted by the software vendor. That works as expected. I also have a subdomain configured to CNAME to a subdomain of the second TLD, call it blog.someOtherTLD.com, on server2.

When I navigate to blog.foo.com I expect to see the contents of blog.SomeOtherTLD.com. Instead I see the cPanel "Apache is working on your cPanel® and WHM™ Server" screen. If I navigate directly to blog.SomeOtherTLD.com however, I see what I was expecting.

Running `tracert` from my home machine resolves correctly to blog.someOtherTLD.com. I tried adding a generic index.html to the folder the subdomain points to, but I still have the cPanel welcome message when I go to blog.foo.com.

Am I missing a configuration setting? Does it matter that foo.com and SomeOtherTLD.com are using different nameservers? On server1, I have little control over content, but I can edit the DNS records. On server2 I have full access to cPanel and DNS settings.

Comment: Edit your question because it is self-contradictory. You mention "another TLD" but the two names you give (foo.com and someothertld.com) are in the SAME TLD.

Comment: @bortzmeyer, I'm out of my element here. Feel free to edit for correctness.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it concerns the use of shared web hosting by end users or resellers, rather than the administration of web hosting.

Answer (score 3):

On the HTTP server, there is probably no configuration for `blog.foo.com`. Since the name of the requested site is sent in the HTTP request, if there is nothing telling the HTTP server what it should do for `blog.foo.com`, it will send back the default page, probably "Apache is working on your cPanel® and WHM™ Server".

You therefore have to add `blog.foo.com` as a name or alias for `blog.SomeOtherTLD.com`. With Apache, this is done with the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` directives.

Comment: As stated here, your not doing a redirect, your sending the whole request to the different server, its requsting blog.foo.com and Apache has no idea what that is.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it had to be something simple I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

that's normal cpanel behaviour.

you need to add blog.foo.com as either 'parked domain' or 'addon domain' for someOtherTLD.com

only then, cpanel will know what content to show for that domain.

Comment: I added it as an add on domain which seemed to work until I clicked a link. That changed the location bar's url to someOtherTLD.com which is less than ideal. If I can't get it to be more seemless with @bortzmeyer's suggestion, I'll switch back to the addon.

Comment: this is another issue and very much related with what script (wordpress/drupal/joomla/etc) you're using? it have nothing to do with cpanel. and most scripts do use full url link instead of relative links. you might also want to consider using frame instead of pointing domain. this way, whatever link you click, it stays inside frame and the url does not change at all.

Answer (score 0):

I completely overcomplicated the situation by leaving the domain I wanted to have displayed on GoDaddy's name servers.

To fix this whole thing and make it easier to work with, I created a new account in cPanel for `foo.com`. Then I created a few subdomains. Then I edited the A record for `foo.com`'s root and set it to the vendor's IP, but left the subdomains set to local account's IP.

All is well now. Thanks for the help, without it I wouldn't have set this up properly in the end.